# Select on join table with exact number of itmes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

- tracks
- tags

One track have many tags

I want to have list of tracks that have both of two tags example tag_id 1 and tag_id 2

```
SELECT * FROM tracks 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tracks.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY track.id
HAVING count(tags.id) = 2
```

The problem if a tracks have tag 1 and 3 it will be listed.

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `distinct` to count

```
SELECT track.id FROM tracks 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tracks.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY track.id
HAVING count(Distinct tags.id) = 2
```

You can change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` since it is converted implicitly based on your Where clause

Answer (score 0):

Your code should do what you want it to.  I would write it as:

```
SELECT track.id
FROM tracks INNER JOIN
     tags 
     ON tracks.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY track.id
HAVING count(tags.id) = 2;
```

Note:

- The `LEFT JOIN` is turned into an `INNER JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause.  You might as well be specific.
- If you have duplicates in `track`, then you want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` rather than `COUNT()`.
- Because you are returning non-aggregated columns, you might get unexpected results in other columns.

Actually, this can be further simplified to:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM tracks t 
WHERE t.tag_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING count(t.id) = 2;
```

The `JOIN` is not needed at all, because you have the information you need in `tracks.tag_id`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, my query is more complicated as that, as in entity I have a join table, not a column in database, the previous post is the successful answer. THANK YOU ANY WAY